# issue in if condition loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

template.html

In django is it possible to check condition like this,I am getting error in this line (incident.other_location or location).

```
{%if newreport_tab and reportperson and incident.manual_date and media  and followup and (incident.other_location or location) and incident.other_incident_type and types%}<a href="{% url incident.views.savereport %}">{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}</a>{%else%}{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}{%endif%}
```

I am  getting this error

```
"TemplateSyntaxError at /report/savereport/
Could not parse the remainder: '(incident.other_location' from 'and(incident.other_location'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `()` (brackets) to combine the operations but instead you can follow the precedence of the operators which are the following:

- or
- and
- not
- in
- ==, !=, <, >,“<=“, >=

Before the `or` evaluation:

```
{%if newreport_tab and reportperson and incident.manual_date and media  and followup and incident.other_location or location and incident.other_incident_type and types%}<a href="{% url incident.views.savereport %}">{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}</a>{%else%}{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}{%endif%}
```

After the `or` evaluation:

```
{%if newreport_tab and reportperson and incident.manual_date and media  and followup and someresult and incident.other_incident_type and types%}<a href="{% url incident.views.savereport %}">{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}</a>{%else%}{% include "buttons/saveandclose.html" %}{%endif%}
```